# How to print eight words to a line using vector<string>?

Tags: string, vector

**I was trying to make a program write 8 words to a line after a user enter their sentence.Its only printing words that have been typed in and i don't have a clue how to make it type 8 words to a line.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

vector<string> sentence;
string sente = "";

void print(string, string);

template<typename T>
void print(vector<T>& v, string)
{

    cout << "Enter your sentence " << endl;

    getline(cin, sente);
    sentence.push_back(sente);

    for (auto const elem: sentence)
    {
        cout << elem;
    }

}

int main()
{
    print(sentence,sente);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using global variables is generally not a good practice.

Also you don't need a extra vector for your use case.

Take a look at the following code, where you can smartly make use of `istringstream` for your use case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

void print()
{

    std::string sente;

    std::cout << "Enter your sentence " << std::endl;

    getline(std::cin, sente);

    // Used to split string around spaces. 
    std::istringstream ss(sente);

    int wordCountPerLine = 0;
    int requiredWordsPerLine = 8;

    // Traverse through all words 
    do { 
        // Read a word 
        std::string word; 
        ss >> word; 

        // Print the read word 
        std::cout << word << " ";

        wordCountPerLine++;

        if(wordCountPerLine % requiredWordsPerLine == 0){
            std::cout<<std::endl;
            wordCountPerLine = 0;
        }

        // While there is more to read 
    } while (ss); 
}

int main()
{
    print();
}
```

Feel free to ask any doubts.

Comment: Will it look the same using a vector<string> or its a little bit complicated?

Comment: For vector, you are unnecessary using extra space